# ¿Cómo puedo pasar una query entera con pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta find() en mongodb a través de pymongo:

```
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
    
    mydb = myclient["test"]
    mycol = mydb["products"]
    query3 = {"$expr": {$gt: [{$size :"$sizesStock"}, 4]   }   }
    
    mydoc3 = mycol.find(query3)
```

Pero resulta en *invalid syntax* en la expresión `$gt`.
He probado a hacer esta consulta en mongodb y sí que me la hace correctamente.

Comment: No se nada de nada de pymongo ni mongodb, pero se lo suficiente de Python como para preguntar ¿$gt no debería estar entre comillas? ¿Y lo mismo con $size?

Comment: Does `{"$expr": {"$gt": [{"$size" :"$sizesStock"}, 4]}}` perform better?

Comment: Thanks to both of us , the problem was the "" on the dollar expressions.